# Spring Boot register a filter after spring security filter is executed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, security-context

I have defined 2 filters which should run on every request, but only after SecurityContextHolder's context is set by spring boot.
However, i always get `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` as null.

Here is my filter configuration:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean SecurityContextHystrixRequestVariableSetterBean() throws Exception {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(securityContextHystrixRequestVariableSetterFilter());
    registration.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return registration;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean HystrixRequestContextEnablerFilterBean() throws Exception {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(hystrixRequestContextEnablerFilter());
    registration.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return registration;
}
```

Filter details:

```
public class SecurityContextHystrixRequestVariableSetterFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        SecurityContextHystrixRequestVariable.getInstance().set(SecurityContextHolder.getContext());

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}

public class HystrixRequestContextEnablerFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HystrixRequestContext context = HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext();
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            context.shutdown();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Comment: It should work, because Spring Security's filter chain is always added in front of all other filters. Did you add a breakpoint in your filter to be sure that your filter is called first?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OncePerRequestFilter`:

```
public class CustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
        //do   
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }    
}

@Configuration
public class CustomConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterAfter(new SecurityFilter(authenticationManager()), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
    }

}
```

Comment: do you mean addFilterAfter?

Comment: @AseemGoyal, fix